# Self-sign certificate not valid for internal request on RHEL

Tags: c#, asp.net, nginx, ssl, rhel

I have .net core web service on RHEL using Nginx. It uses https with self-signed certificate.

config for Nginx is:

```
listen 443 ssl;
server_name  _;

ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/my_cert.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/my_cert.key;
```

With this config and self-signed certificate I had error in communications with web service - service sends request to itself. The error was

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
> ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

I decided to make the certificate trusted. Added it to `/usr/share/pki/ca-trust-source/anchors/` folder then used `update-ca-trust` command.

After that I had another error on the server:

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Connection refused
> ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (111): Connection refused

How can I resolve this problem with certificate and is my way right?

**One more thing:**
Connection refused error occur after client successfully connected to web service and web service trying to connect to itself (another endpoint)

Comment: *Connection refused* is unrelated to certificates but means that the TCP connection can not be established. Without being able to establish a TCP connection it is not possible to start the TLS handshake in the first place - and certificate validation happens only after receiving the certificate inside the TLS handshake. Connection refused might happen if the server is not started, not listening on the expected port, firewalls blocking connections etc.

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich Connection refused error occur after client successfully connected to web service and web service trying to connect to itself (another endpoint)

Comment: Are you 100% sure your self-signed certificate got really imported? Can you grep it inside a trust file under `/usr/share/pki/`? In my experience, people are often missing the _CA:TRUE_ extension which causes the `update-ca-trust` import to skip that certificate.